# File Manager of CKEditor WolfCMS not working with Nginx

Tags: apache, nginx, url-rewriting, ckeditor

I migrated a WolfCMS from Apache to Nginx. Everything is working fine except for the CKEditor File Manager plugin. When opening the `browser server` box of CKEditor I am seeing `No input file specified.` All other friendly URLs, rewrites are working without any issues. So I assume the issue is related to a wrong Nginx configuration.

These are the **Apache** rewrites:

```
RewriteEngine On
# Set next line to your Wolf CMS root - if not in subdir, then just /
#RewriteBase /wolfcms/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
# Main URL rewriting.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?WOLFPAGE=$1 [L,QSA]
```

For **Nginx** the docs just state:

```
#Put the following code in your server block:

try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?WOLFPAGE=$uri&$args;
```

And that is what I did. The file manager URL that is not working in Nginx is:

`/wolf_ckeditor/filemanager/index.php?type=Images&CKEditor=part_0_content&CKEditorFuncNum=1&langCode=de`

=> Leading to `No input file specified.`

Any suggestions on how I could modify my Nginx config to get this working again?

Comment: Can you try this one instead(remeber to reload or restart nginx after the change) https://gist.github.com/AshWilliams/96aa1444d23bf12f5522eb540b6160eb

Comment: Not working. When using this, it downloads the actual php file when requesting /admin.